# Asp textbox treat its content as number instead of text

Tags: asp.net, string, textbox, numbers, exp

I wish to show a large string in an asp:TextBox.
The string is just series of numbers, but i wish to treat it as a text.

Currently ASP tries to be clever and the textbox shows 
2.10002e+006

instead of 
210001800230...

Is there a way to control this?

Thank you
A

Comment: can you give an example of how you are assigning the value to the `TextBox` because it shouldn't be doing anything to it if you just assigning a string to the `Text` property.  Some code would make the issue easier to diagnose.

Comment: i think u just check the value before, which is going to be in textbox

Comment: turned out to be my mistake, the original data was corrupted in the database, and wrongly put to the textbox, sorry about that